# Difference between execute() and executeSIngle() methods in ActiveAndroid library?

Tags: android, sqlite, activeandroid

I am new to **ActiveAndroid** and I am stuck with Querying the database. 
Please help me out with the difference between `execute()` and `executeSingle()` methods in `ActiveAndroid` Library?

Both these methods are used to query the database but I am not getting when to use the former and when to use the later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between `execute()` and `executeSingle()` is somewhat explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Querying-the-database):

> If we only want to get items from a certain category, we pass in a string for our where class argument. The method would look like this:

```
public static Item getRandom(Category category) {
    return new Select()
        .from(Item.class)
        .where("Category = ?", category.getId())
        .orderBy("RANDOM()")
        .executeSingle();
}
```

> And here's how we get all the items in a category, sorted by name.

```
public static List<Item> getAll(Category category) {
    return new Select()
        .from(Item.class)
        .where("Category = ?", category.getId())
        .orderBy("Name ASC")
        .execute();
}
```

As you see, `execute()` returns a list, while `executeSingle()` returns a single object.

In the examples above, the first would return a random object matching the query, while the second would return all the objects in an ascending order.

In other words, use `executeSingle()` to return the first result, and use `execute()` to return a list with all objects.

Answer (score 5):

The **execute()** returns a list of objects while **executeSingle()** returns the first element of executed query returned list.

So return value of **execute()** is a list and return value of **executeSingle()** is a single object.